# Is it possible to get data from a Flash object?

Tags: php, flash

I use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for grabbing data from sites, but now I need to grab content from Flash objects. I haven't had any experience in flash, so could you tell me, is it possible in general? If yes, what will I need to learn in order to perform this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible, depending of how many efforts you could put in it. What content do you need? If you only need images, you could read [SWF Format Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf), parse swf into tags, find DefineBitsJPEG ones and save their data.

Comment: Static text resides in DefineText tags. But text also may be converted to vector contours (no glyph codes, graphics only). Also, swf may render text programmatically, and that would require parse ActionScript bytecode from DoABC tags (after all, SWF is a program).
Edit: Static text (which was simply put to stage in Flash IDE) is easy enough to extract; all other is not.

Comment: Before diving into swf parsing, you could also use SWiX (http://www.swixkit.com/) to see if static text would suffice. If swf structure contains DefineText and there is text you need, you may try to parse it.
If you decide to parse, see that pdf - you will need header format, tag header format, and DefineText format - that's all. Couple days of work (maybe).
And ActionScript - no, you don't need it (now).